# What happens if you run out of malaria pills?

Tags: far-cry-2

In Far Cry 2, your character has malaria, for which he needs to regularly acquire and take medication.

I know that it's possible to run out of pills, because I have, but I immediately did a mission for the refugees and they gave me more.

**What happens if you don't have any malaria pills when an attack comes on?**

Also, near the end of the game,

> You pass the point of no return, just after meeting the Jackal in the prison. Is it possible to run out of malaria pills after that point? If so, what happens then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always possible to run out. If you do, you black out and wake up in either a church or a doctors' surgery depending on what stage in the game you're at.

Comment: Interesting!  Can this be used as a way to travel back to the main game after you pass the point of no return?

Comment: "Actually it's not true, I have malaria in the 2nd point of them game and I just keep going back to my last save and I can't make it to any people that give me malaria pills" by an anonymous user